# How computationally difficult is it to determine if two function fields are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, function-fields

Determining if two **number** fields are isomorphic is a hard problem, according to Cohen in his book *A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory*.

> Is determining if two **function** fields are isomorphic a hard problem? Is there a reference?